# Gradle files not recognised in new directory structure?

Tags: gradle, intellij-14

Previously we made a Gradle project in Intellij and all the gradle files were there under the project. However, we have now moved the files in this project to a sub folder, but the Gradle files aren't being recognised. The picture below is the new folder set up where our code from the original project is now in the server folder (where the Gradle files are). When I mark the src folder (under server) as the Sources Root, that is when the dependencies from Gradle aren't recognised.

[image: File structure after moving the folder]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the correct way to go is actually to separate out the client/server folder into two separate modules.